# Is the circumference of a unit circle irrational?

Tags: circles, pi

> Let us assume that I have a unit circle, and there are no existence of errors in measurement of a quantity. Is the circumference irrational, like the diagonal of a unit square?

Edit : My apologies. For a moment the realisation that circumference is irrational was making me feel "How is that possible? Lengths are meant to be rational", until I happened to remember the formula of the diagonal of a square, and after reading a few comments I realised(for the lack of a better word) it is a usual fact when dealing with circles.

My apologies if it caused unnecessary waste of time on your behalf. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: A unit circle is a circle whose radius is length $1$.  So the circumference is $C = 2\pi r= 2\pi$.  Yes, $2\pi$ is irrational.  Yes, the circumference of a unit circle is irrational...."Does it mean I need to change my outlook, or can it be understood just as normally as the statement "the length of a unit line segment is 1"?" Huh?  I don't understand....

Comment: *"How is that possible? Lengths are meant to be rational"* ... You may be interested to know that *almost-no* lengths (among all possible measurements in real numbers) are rational. ... A rational number is the solution of a linear equation $ax+b=0$ w/integer $a$ and $b$. If we broaden our scope to include solutions of *polynomial* equations w/integer coefficients (eg, $\sqrt2$ satisfies $x^2-2=0$), we get the "algebraic numbers", and they still don't make a dent. "Almost-all" numbers are ["transcendental"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number) (ie, *weird*), like $\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

The circumference of a unit circle would be $2 \pi$ (since $c = 2 \pi r$), so it would be irrational. I'm not sure what you mean by "change your outlook," but $\pi$ is a pretty universally understood quantity. It's the ratio between a circle's circumference and diameter.

Answer (score 0):

> For a moment the realisation that circumference is irrational was making me feel "How is that possible? Lengths are meant to be rational"

Ah.  That's very important and yes, your outlook should change.

In geometric space, the world is a continuum and lengths can be any (non-negative) values.  You can't have a distance or length that can't exist.  There aren't any "atoms" where one distance is possible but another is not.

Or at least Euclid thought so when he claimed "Any straight line segment can be extended indefinitely in a straight line" in which he was claiming distances exist for every possible positive value (although Max Planck may have another opinion).

It's actual *because* of this irrational numbers became such a problem.  It'd be fine to Pythagoras that all values are rational and although $r^2 = 2$ for rational $r$ is impossible, he'd accept that as $\sqrt 2$ simply need not exist and we could live in a universe without them.... except the diagonal of a square must be an $x$ where $x^2 =2$ and $x$ *can't* be rational.  But it *must* exist.

====

The diagonal of a unit square is $\sqrt 2$ which is irrational.

The circumference of a unit circle is $2\pi$ which is irrational.

I don't know what in your outlook made the concept difficult while the concept of a the diagonal of a square being irrational was okay.  But given the options I'd say, yes, it is just as normally understood.

A geometric figure will have many measurable qualities (sides, diagonals, radii, angles, area etc) many interrelated.  The ratios between them need not be rational.  If one's outlook is that this is strange then, yes, it should be changed. If one's outlook is that this is normal (actually, inevetible) then it need not be changed.